# Merging a new object in java with an already existing one

Tags: java, arrays

I want to know how can i merge two objects in java. I've tried creating a 3rd class but to no avail. The first one being the `this` object and the next one is given through the method.  Something like:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public final class IntegerArray {
    private int[] a;

    public IntegerArray(int[] a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public int length() {
        return a.length;
    }

    public int getElementAt(int i) {
        return a[i];
    }

    public int sum() {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i: a) {
            sum += i;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public double average() {
        int i, sum = 0, armean;
        for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + a[i];
        }
        armean = sum / i;
        return armean;
    }

    public IntegerArray getSorted() {
        int[] b = a.clone();
        Arrays.sort(b);
        return new IntegerArray(b);
    }

    public IntegerArray contact(IntegerArray ia) {
        IntegerArray merged  = new IntegerArray(this.a);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return a.toString();
    }


}
```

Comment: please show some codes and what you have done so far.

Comment: Are you trying to merge two objects or combine the elements from two different arrays? Not sure what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "merge"?

Comment: There is no generic way to merge all type of objects. You have to write that functionality yourself. Keep in mind that for some types (for example Collection#add All) this does already exist.

Comment: @Zephyr Get the elements from the new object and add them to the existing one aka the `this` object.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Any code you can show?

Comment: @Zephyr I'm asking because I don't know where to start i don't know the logic behind it. I'm not looking for a direct code answer any hint/tip will be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is, from what you've provided, we don't know what you're trying to accomplish. Maybe include some of your code and indicate the portion you're stuck on. What are your input values and what do you expect to get back in return?

Comment: @Zephyr Edited to show my full class. I want to get the `this` object from this class and add the values of  object `ia` (as seen on the contact method), returning a new object with the values of `this` object and the `ia` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your merge method, you need to create a new `int[]`, one whose length is the size of the `this.a.length` + the other object's length, use for loops to place the `this.a` values into the new array, and then another for-loop to place the merging object's array's values in. Note that you must be careful to use the correct indices for the new array when adding inthe 2nd array -- you must add the first int array's length to the index when referencing the new array item. Then create a new IntegerArray object with this newly created longer array.

```
public IntegerArray merge(IntegerArray other) {
    int[] newA = new int[a.length + other.a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        newA[i] = a[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < other.a.length; i++) {
        // here is where you need to be careful about the index
        newA[i + a.length] = other.a[i];
    }
    return new IntegerArray(newA);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the contact() method, you need to create an array whose length is equal to the sum of the lengths of the this.a and ia, arrays then copy the this.a array into that new array and also copy the contents of ia into it. Then you can create a new IntegerArray passing that new array as the argument to the constructor.

```
  int temp[] = new int[sum_of_lengths];
  // copy this.a elements into temp
  // copy ia elements into temp
  IntegerArray merged = new IntegerArray(temp);
```

Aah - @DontKnowMuchBut beat me by a few seconds